# override session for user timeout value in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Can anyone help me how to override the session timeout for the user drupal 7?

I use the autologout module but its not working.
thats why im planning to override the session.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I tried to use the Automated Logout module https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout and change the Timeout (seconds) for the user role that I wanted to limit the session but it did not work.

Comment: did you tried this module https://www.drupal.org/project/session_limit ?

Comment: Hi Fky, I already tried that.
btw, I got memcache and simplesamlauth module and im not sure if thats affect the session timeout.